# 3D objects won't rotate when click during game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm developing a 3D game for Android platform in a first person style. During one part into the game, the player clicks an object (Item), and the object should be rotated in 45 degrees.

The problem begins when by clicking the object, I can see in the log console the angles and the values have changed, but the player can't see in the game itself the object (In this matter is a form object, like square) has rotated.

I have tried several ways to make the object rotate inside the game, so the player could see it, but without success.

Here is the relevant block of code (One of my tries to solve the problem):

```
if (array[i].name == "Quad")
{
    Debug.Log("Quad object hitted");
    Quaternion rotation_value = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().rotation;
    Vector3 angle = rotation_value.eulerAngles;
                               
    Debug.Log(angle);
    Vector3 rot = new Vector3(0, 90, (angle.z + 45));

    Quaternion rot2;
    rot2.eulerAngles = rot;
                            
    hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().rotation = rot2; 
}
```

Any help / suggestion of alternative code in order to solve it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Unity documentation on Transforms:

> [Do not attempt to edit/modify rotation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)

Instead use the Rotate() method for a Transform component. It will modify the Transforms local rotation.

For example:
`hit.transform.Rotate(0f, 45f, 0f);`
will add a rotation of 45 degrees on the Y-axis every time it's called.

---

Fixing your code to make this work would look similar to:

```
if (array[i].name == "Quad")
{
    hit.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 45f);
}
```

---

The Unity documentation for further reading: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: Thanks about answer, I have read the documentation and tried to solve the problem with the code change with Rotate method, but still the forms don't rotate.

Comment: Are you certain the transform you're interacting with is the correct one?